# Разработка полного цикла

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, nginx, java-ee

Доброго времени суток!
Начал продумывать тему и структуру своего дипломного проекта (учусь на Computer Science). В качестве темы выбрана разработка полного цикла веб-сервиса для университета, то есть как разработка фронтэнда, так и бекэнда. Собственно, я сделал некоторые наброски на тему технологий, которые мне будет необходимо использовать в данной работе и хотел бы кое-что по ней прояснить.
Весь проект - реализация паттерна MVC, то есть существуют ярко выраженные части: данные для сайта(Model), клиентский интерфейс (View) и прослойка между ними (Controller). Первое и последнее это бекенд, а второе - фронт.
На бекенде будет крутиться блок из трех программ: Nginx (для отдачи статических данных: статических страниц, картинок, стилей), БД (например MySQL) и рукописная программа на Java, которая будет обрабатывать динамические данные (получать от Nginx запросы, посылать их в БД, как-то обрабатывать и отдавать клиенту через Nginx).
Если с первым и вторым вопросов не очень много (конфигурация серверов гуглится и пишется по документации), то в последнем есть сложность. Какие технологии будут использоваться? Я думаю, что будет два больших блока: связь с БД (что-то типа JDBC, верно?) и связь с Nginx (видимо WebSockets). Или же мне надо смотреть в сторону Java EE и Spring?
Фронтэнд будет состоять из движка и CMS, чтобы можно было создавать новые страницы (новости, например). Для этой цели пишется некий движок (или берется готовый) на HTML+CSS+JS, на него натягивается интерфейс и в нужные места втыкаются куски, которые будут отображать динамику из Java-бекэнда.

Я вообще в нужную сторону двигаюсь или сейчас вывалил кучу несвязных слов и технологий? Заранее спасибо за ответ на это полотно!

Comment: Я тут недавно, и пока не вполне понимаю, насколько тут сообщество толерантно к таким вопросам. Вот, в общем и целом вроде план разумный. Я разве что недолюбливаю Java, но это мой личный запрыг. И неясно, для чего вам WebSockets -- nginx их разве что проксировать будет, управляться они будут, видимо, из Java, и нужны они только для реалтаймовой доставки событий. Вам это точно надо? UPD: и я не вижу никаких планов на кэширование.

Comment: А что вместо Java Вы предложите на свой вкус? Node.JS (io.js)? Я, откровенно говоря, не очень в теме построения веб-сервисов, это мой первый нормальный опыт сложнее отдачи джавой статической странички. Каким образом тогда Nginx должен соединяться с контроллером? Системными сообщениями? А если, в теории, масштабировать проект и разносить статику и динамику на разные физические машины? Считаю, что лучше с заделом на будущее сразу повесить все связи на сетевые протоколы, чтобы потом отмасштабироваться поднятием второй машины и сменой айпишников

Comment: Для вебсокетов -- да, я бы предложил нод/io.js + socket.io, там асинхронку делать проще всего, а API сервера и клиента очень похожи, не в последнюю очередь языком. Nginx в таких проектах используется как прокси (в т. ч. обратный) и/или балансировщик нагрузки (когда "контроллеров" много одинаковых). Соединяется с рабочим (upstream) сервером через сокет, передаёт чуть видоизменённые HTTP-запросы, сообщая о реальном адресе клиента в заголовках вроде X-Forwarded-For. Да, статику можно вынести аж на отдельный домен, на CDN какую-нибудь.

Comment: я бы отнес View скорее к бэкенду, чем к фронтенду, CMS на фронтенде тоже не бывает.

Answer (score 4):

Если описывать автомобиль по такой схеме, то получится что-то вроде "Структуру я продумал. Машина будет состоять из трех основных агрегатов: бампер, антенна и самодельная конструкция, к которая будет отвечать за всё остальное. При этом шасси будет в месте отправления, а кузов - в месте прибытия. Пассажиры будут сидеть в ковше".

Чтобы как-то поправить эту схему, несколько пояснений.

1. MVC - это не любая система, которая состоит из трех частей. Этак и про квартиру можно сказать, что модель - это мебель, вью - это обои, а про контроллер придумать ещё какую-нибудь отсебятину. MVC - это паттерн **взаимодействия объектов в рамках одной и той же программы.** То есть, термин применим только к той самой рукописной программе. В которой моделью будет собственно логика приложения, контроллером - блок, принимающий и обрабатывающий запросы, а представлением - блок, форматирующий вывод. А сама эта программа будет представлять из себя 95% всей системы.
2. То есть, говоря "система", должны иметь в виду ту самую "самописную программу". А Nginx, mysql - это все незначительные детали. Nginx - это просто прокси сервис, а mysql - храниище, аналог файловой системы. Чисто служебные программы.
3. Не очень понятно, что имеется в виду под "веб-сервисом". Если это классический *веб-сервис*, то ему не нужен ни фронтенд, ни вью - он тупо отдаёт XML по запросам. Если же это веб-сайт, предоставляющий какой-либо сервис пользователям, то структура веб-сайта в корне отличается от описанной. в частности, на HTML+CSS+JS движки не пишут, а движком является та самая самописная программа. И фронтенд в этом случае несет чисто декоративную нагрузку, не занимаясь логикой. А вебсокеты тут никаким боком не нужны.

В общем, плясать надо (как всегда при проектировании чего-либо) от *предметной области*. Если это веб-сайт - значит xCGI с аяксом. Если чат - то вебсокеты. Если веб-сервис - то REST.

Comment: Планируется разработать что-то вроде корпоративного портала для факультета. То есть имеется база данных со студентами и внутренней документацией. На сайте должна быть возможность заполнения анкет новых студентов и документов на различные мероприятия. После этого добавляется "корпоративный" функционал: постановка задач подчиненным, внутренние чаты и так далее